# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected OnClientClick

Tags: asp.net, javascript, onclientclick

I was just doing a quick test of something, and before I could really get started I got this error. I have no C# code yet and this is my aspx code:

```
 <script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
        function myOnClick() {
            //if (TextBox1.Text != null)
                //DropDownList1.Visible = true;
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <title>TEST</title>
```

and

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="return showMore();" runat=server  Text="V" />
```

And I get the error at this line:

```
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="V" onclick="return showMore();" id="Button1" />
```

while debugging...

Any ideas?

THANKS!!!

Comment: Your `OnClientClick` property has the `ShowMore()` method listed, while the JS method in your first code block has the fn name listed as `myOnClick()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function named "showMore()".

Comment: wow. don't i look like an idiot... Thanks! Although the function still produces an error because it can't find the object TextBox1. Any ideas? I should proly start a new questions for that though...

Comment: Well, I figured the additional error out myself so I'll just post it. Must use: `document.getElementById("<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>")` to get the asp object. Thanks!

Comment: Yep... thats pretty standard when dealing with ASP.NET.